# Hace vs hacía en el pasado

Tags: preposiciones, conjugación, tiempos-pasados

> Uno de los hallazgos más inusuales fue que, más que un cambuche, la
>   banda había construido **hacía dos meses** una base rústica en un
>   antiguo secadero de café

En este ejemplo ¿por qué se usa «hacía» y no «hace»?

¿Sería correcto en este caso sustituir «hace» por «hacía»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ayer se enteró de que ya se habían marchado **hace** dos días.

Se habían marchado dos días antes del momento actual. Un día se marcharon, el día siguiente se enteró y el día siguiente a ese es hoy. En inglés sería "two days **ago**".

> Ayer se enteró de que ya se habían marchado **hacía** dos días.

Se habían marchado dos días antes del momento del que se habla. Un día se marcharon, dos días después se enteró y el día después de enterarse es hoy. En inglés sería "two days **before**".

Comment: I’ve always found this hard to understand. So, something like: ‘Yesterday he/she found out they had left two days ago’ vs ‘’yesterday he/she found out they had left two days before’?

Comment: @Traveller Correct. I added that to my answer.